# SimpleSamlPHP Heroku Lost State

Tags: simplesamlphp

I have simpleSaml integrated with codeignighter and everything works with 1 dyno, but as soon as I increase the dynos to 1 or more, I start loosing state information. I am thinking that the cookies are not getting updated properly but I am not sure. I tried using memcached to no avail. Does anyone know why this would start happening with more then one dyno?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Saml uses a php session for storing state. Usually, when this error happens, the session has been accidentally cleared or can not be found.

I don't know what dyno is (guessing it is easy deployment for an application server) but when you go to two, the client is being redirected to the second dyno (which has no session for the user).

If there is any way to use sticky sessions when load balancing between the two dynos, this should solve the problem.

Comment: So I would agree with this approach but I removed the PHP store and flipped to a direct SQL storage. I feel like that should have resolved issue regardless if the redirect goes to a second dyno (second deployed app).

Comment: So you have modified the php session.save_handler to something that uses a shared SQL server?

Comment: Or I am guessing you are using SimpleSaml's config.php option for using memcache. You may want try Heroku's own documented method for handling php sessions. No simplesaml configuration required.